# Event Log Web Event Task Category ID

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, event-viewer

Can anyone tell me what the Task Category ID is for a Web Event used in the Event Viewer?

```
 _eventLog.WriteEntry(eventText, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 1001, [value for web event]);
```

Comment: All I can find is [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/customizing-event-log-categories/184405714). I think you might have to define a custom task category using a message file.